# Rubys on Rails project Using Aptana

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, aptana

I am having a major issue with creating a Rails Project on Aptana (using mac os x).  Basically, when i try starting a Rails project and name a file, it comes back with an error saying:

"!!! Path to log file not valid: /Users/fab/Documents/Aptana Studio Workspace/test.rb/log/mongrel.log mongrel::start reported an error. Use mongrel_rails mongrel::start -h to get help."

and then a pop up comes up saying: "Rename the directory to no longer have a space"

After all this, i tried renaming the directory without spaces, but then when i went back to create a new project again it came back with this pop up that says "resource'/fab/public'does not exist." Under this there is a list of two options: "periodic workshop save" and "replace project index file."

What does this mean, and how can i fix the problem?

Any advise would be much appreciated!

Omarj

Answer (score 1):

Mongrel used to have a bug with writing log files, and for whatever reason it's trying to create a path relative to a file (rather than a folder) in your case. i think they also had issues with spaces in the path.

Do NOT rename your workspace path, or Studio/RadRails won't see the files anymore (as you saw above) - because you moved them.

I suggest renaming the folder back. This question is pretty stale, so mongrel is no longer widely used. you could try one of the other server types, like webrick.

Answer (score 0):

Hey, I don't have an answer to your question. However, would advise you that if you are starting to get your hands dirty with Ruby and Rails, then consider TextMate as your IDE instead of RadRails.